How do I create a platform-neutral JavaFX jar (which contains executable code) for use with another multiplatform application?
My organization is working on a large Java application with an old code base mostly written in Swing, and I have been tasked with working on an offshoot project that will be managed independently, written using JavaFX (in Temurin JDK 21, so JavaFX is not bundled) and managed with the Kotlin Gradle DSL. This project contains a panel and some business logic and also has two main methods to test it independently (one in Main.java, and one in the UI panel, Planner.java).
I would like to publish it to our artefactory, but I am not having any luck structuring my build.gradle.kts file to be able to:

Run the class with the main method; and
Create a jar that does not have a dependency a platform-specific implementation of JavaFX.

This is where I am now:
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

plugins {
    java
    application
    `maven-publish`

    // I can't imagine this is necessary but my module isn't able to import JavaFX without it.
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.14"
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
    }
}

val isRelease = project.hasProperty("release")
val appVersion = "0.1" + if (isRelease) "" else "-SNAPSHOT"
val modulePath by lazy { "${configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().asPath}:build/classes/java/main" }
val moduleString by lazy { javafx.modules.joinToString(separator = ",") }

application {
    version = appVersion
    group = "my.organization.subproject"
    mainClass.set("my.organization.subproject.fx.Main")
    mainModule.set("AutoMosaic")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "21"
    modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.swing")

    // When this is enabled, I cannot run the classes with Main methods.
    configuration = "compileOnly"
}

val javafxPlatform: String = when {
    OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX && System.getProperty("os.arch") == "aarch64" -> "mac-aarch64" // ARM Mac
    OperatingSystem.current().isMacOsX && System.getProperty("os.arch") == "x86_64" -> "mac" // Intel Mac
    OperatingSystem.current().isWindows -> "win"
    OperatingSystem.current().isLinux -> "linux"
    else -> throw GradleException("Unsupported OS for JavaFX")
}

dependencies {
    // In an attempt to only rely on platform-neutral dependencies.
    compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-base:21")
    compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:21")
    compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:21")
    compileOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-swing:21")

    // To execute Main and Planner locally.
    runtimeOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-base:21:$javafxPlatform")
    runtimeOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:21:$javafxPlatform")
    runtimeOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:21:$javafxPlatform")
    runtimeOnly("org.openjfx:javafx-swing:21:$javafxPlatform")
}

// To create the Main and Planner Gradle tasks that can be run.
fun createJavaExecTask(taskName: String, mainClassName: String) {
    tasks.register<JavaExec>(taskName) {
        group = "application"
        mainClass.set(mainClassName)
        jvmArgs = listOf(
            "--module-path", modulePath,
            "--add-modules", moduleString
        )
        classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    }
}

// To run these through IDEA, configure Gradle tasks with Tasks and Arguments:
// 1. Main: main
// 2. Planner: planner
// Then they should be runnable via IDEA. The issue is that the module path for the JavaFX jars
// managed by the plugin are incredibly obtuse and can change, so even grabbing them and
// hard-coding them in an Application task yields issues.
createJavaExecTask("main", "my.organization.subproject.fx.Main")
createJavaExecTask("planner", "my.organization.subproject.fx.Planner")

// Print the arguments necessary to configure an IDEA task.
tasks.register("jvmOpts") {
    doLast {
        println("JVM opts required to make an IDEA task:")
        println("--module-path $modulePath --add-modules $moduleString")
    }
}

val repositoryUrl = "https://jfrog.organization.edu/artifactory/apt-maven"

val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            groupId = "my.organization.mainproject"
            from(components["java"])
            artifact(sourcesJar.get())
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            val repoPassword: String? by project
            val repoUsername: String? by project
            url = uri(repositoryUrl + (if (project.hasProperty("release")) { "-releases" } else { "-snapshots" }))
            credentials {
                username = repoUsername
                password = repoPassword
            }
        }
    }
}


I'm not a Gradle expert in areas like this: any help at all would be immensely appreciated.

"Create a jar that does not have a dependency a platform-specific implementation of JavaFX." -> In Maven that would be a provided scope.  For Gradle, I don't know.

"Run the class with the main method" -> Depends on whether it is a modular jar or not, the command for building a modular jar with a main class, is different than that for a non-modular jar.  The example linked is from the command line.  For Gradle, I don't know.  Also, the app won't run unless the JavaFX modules are sourced from somewhere (e.g. placed on the module path using a JRE that includes JavaFX or via command line switches).

Based on your stated goals and current build script, I think the the following build script examples should at least help point you in the right direction. Some notes:

I (non-exhaustively) tested the examples with Gradle 8.11.

Both examples use version 0.1.0 of the org.openjfx.javafxplugin plugin. That is the latest version as of this answer, and is required to make the examples work. Other Gradle projects that depend on your project may also need to apply the plugin in order for the correct JavaFX artifacts to be found.
The version you're using (0.0.14), and older versions, work differently and will lead to the classifier being included in the generated POM (e.g., <classifier>win</classifier>).

I applied the Java Library Plugin instead of the Application Plugin. It seems like your project is more of a library than an application. You could apply both plugins, but you don't really seem to be using any of the features of the Application Plugin currently.

For the first example, since you seem to be creating a library, I put the JavaFX dependencies in the api configuration. That assumes your public API exposes JavaFX. It also leads the dependencies in the generated POM being put in the compile scope. You could use the implementation configuration if your public API does not expose JavaFX. Note that will put the dependencies in the generated POM in the runtime scope.

The withSourcesJar() in the java block automatically adds a sourcesJar task and the JAR created by that task will be included in the Maven publication. You can add a withJavadocJar() call if you want to include a JAR of the project's Javadoc.

Your current build script indicates your project has a module-info.java file. So, I set the mainModule properties of both JavaExec tasks. That combined with modularity.inferModulePath being true (by default), the task will put the files in the classpath property on the --module-path and launch the program via --module. At least that's how it works on recent versions of Gradle.

The two registered JavaExec tasks depend on the jar task, and the JAR is put on the module-path instead of main.output. Both again because your current build script indicates your project is modular. This is one way to ensure any resources (i.e., those files under src/main/resources) end up inside your module. It's also how the run task from the Application Plugin is configured to work for modular projects.


Include JavaFX Dependencies in POM
plugins {
  id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.1.0"
  `java-library`
  `maven-publish`
}

val isRelease = hasProperty("release")

group = "my.organization.subproject"
version = "0.1" + if (isRelease) "" else "-SNAPSHOT"

java {
  withSourcesJar()
  toolchain {
    languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  val javafxVersion = "21.0.5"
  api("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javafxVersion")
  api("org.openjfx:javafx-swing:$javafxVersion")
}

publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
      from(components["java"])
    }
  }

  repositories {
    maven {
      val baseUrl = "https://jfrog.organization.edu/artifactory/apt-maven-"
      url = uri(baseUrl + if (isRelease) "release" else "snapshot")
      credentials {
        username = findProperty("repoUsername")?.toString() ?: ""
        password = findProperty("repoPassword")?.toString() ?: ""
      }
    }
  }
}

tasks {
  val main by sourceSets
  val modPath = (main.runtimeClasspath - main.output) + files(jar.flatMap { it.archiveFile })

  register<JavaExec>("runMain") {
    dependsOn(jar)
    group = "application"

    mainModule = "AutoMosaic"
    mainClass = "my.organization.subproject.fx.Main"
    classpath = modPath
  }

  register<JavaExec>("runPlanner") {
    dependsOn(jar)
    group = "application"

    mainModule = "AutoMosaic"
    mainClass = "my.organization.subproject.fx.Planner"
    classpath = modPath
  }
}

This will generate the following POM when publishing to your Maven repository (the project's name is example in this case):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- This module was also published with a richer model, Gradle metadata,  -->
  <!-- which should be used instead. Do not delete the following line which  -->
  <!-- is to indicate to Gradle or any Gradle module metadata file consumer  -->
  <!-- that they should prefer consuming it instead. -->
  <!-- do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.organization.subproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>21.0.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
      <version>21.0.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

If you want the dependencies to end up in the provided scope, then unfortnately there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that. See How Map gradle 'compileOnly' to 'provided' in generated pom (generatePom...) for a potential solution, but I don't know how to translate that Groovy DSL into the Kotlin DSL. Note a popular JavaFX library, ControlsFX, simply removes the JavaFX dependencies from the generated POM. So, you may just want to use the second example's approach.
Exclude JavaFX Dependnecies from POM
This excludes the JavaFX dependencies by defining a custom configuration (named javafx in this example). The Maven Publish Plugin won't include dependencies from that configuration, at least not by default. Then the compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath configurations are configured to extend from the javafx configuration to ensure JavaCompile and JavaExec tasks continue to work (or at least make it easier to configure them).
plugins {
  id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.1.0"
  `java-library`
  `maven-publish`
}

val isRelease = hasProperty("release")

group = "my.organization.subproject"
version = "0.1" + if (isRelease) "" else "-SNAPSHOT"

java {
  withSourcesJar()
  toolchain {
    languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  val javafx = create("javafx")
  compileClasspath.configure {
    extendsFrom(javafx)
  }
  runtimeClasspath.configure {
    extendsFrom(javafx)
  }
}

dependencies {
  val javafxVersion = "21.0.5"
  "javafx"("org.openjfx:javafx-controls:$javafxVersion")
  "javafx"("org.openjfx:javafx-swing:$javafxVersion")
}

publishing {
  publications {
    create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
      from(components["java"])
    }
  }

  repositories {
    maven {
      val baseUrl = "https://jfrog.organization.edu/artifactory/apt-maven-"
      url = uri(baseUrl + if (isRelease) "release" else "snapshot")
      credentials {
        username = findProperty("repoUsername")?.toString() ?: ""
        password = findProperty("repoPassword")?.toString() ?: ""
      }
    }
  }
}

tasks {
  val main by sourceSets
  val modPath = (main.runtimeClasspath - main.output) + files(jar.flatMap { it.archiveFile })

  register<JavaExec>("runMain") {
    dependsOn(jar)
    group = "application"

    mainModule = "AutoMosaic"
    mainClass = "my.organization.subproject.fx.Main"
    classpath = modPath
  }

  register<JavaExec>("runPlanner") {
    dependsOn(jar)
    group = "application"

    mainModule = "AutoMosaic"
    mainClass = "my.organization.subproject.fx.Planner"
    classpath = modPath
  }
}

This will generate the following POM when publishing to your Maven repository (the project's name is example in this case):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- This module was also published with a richer model, Gradle metadata,  -->
  <!-- which should be used instead. Do not delete the following line which  -->
  <!-- is to indicate to Gradle or any Gradle module metadata file consumer  -->
  <!-- that they should prefer consuming it instead. -->
  <!-- do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.organization.subproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>

